# Why does this table name require back-ticks?

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I am seeing a curious name dependency in the following MySQL table definition. When I code the table as shown, it seems to break MySQL. When I perform "select * from dictionary_pair_join" from MySQLQueryBrowser, the status bar says "No resultset returned" -- no column names and no errors. When I insert a row into the table, the status bar says "1 row affected by the last command, no resultset returned", and subsequent selects give the same "No resultset returned" response.

When I enclose the tablename in backticks in the "select" statement, all works fine. Surely there are no mysql entities named "dictionary_pair_join"!

Here is the table definition:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dictionary_pair_join;
CREATE TABLE dictionary_pair_join (
  version_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0',
  pair_id int(11) UNSIGNED default NULL,
  KEY (version_id),
  KEY (pair_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is the broken select statement:

```
select * from dictionary_pair_join;
```

Here is its working counterpart:

```
select * from `dictionary_pair_join`;
```

Why are backticks required in the select statement?

Update: This also fails in the Python mysqldb interface, which is why I started looking at it. I can put the backticks into my Python "select" generators, but I was hoping this was some stupid and easily-changed nit. I suppose I can also find a different name.

Comment: Does it work in command line `mysql`?

Comment: seems like a bug, because for me it works fine even without backticks.. I am using MySQL 5.5

Comment: Hold on, I'll check...

Comment: Yes, it seems to work fine (without backticks) from the command line.

Comment: Curiously, it also fails in mysqldb from Python -- the reason why I started looking at it. Sounds like a bug, I'm using version 5.0.77-community-nt, Win64 (this is the latest I can find that is compatible with my Python, mysqldb, and windows combination).

Comment: Possibly because 'MySQL query browser' uppercases the join due to a poorly designed regex, or some other awkward query transform.

Comment: The Query Browser tool went EOL years ago. http://www.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html I see the issue is this tool, not MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've uprated the comments from Quassnoi and Software Guy, together they've persuaded me that it's just a bug in mysql/mysqldb/mysqlquerybrowser.

I changed the table name (to "dictionary_pair_cons") and the problem went away, in both the query browser and mysqldb.